# How to validate requestbody which contains multiple valid json requests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

When I supply multiple json request under request body for POST request, very first request gets accepted while rest of gets ignored.

*I don't want to send list as request infact I am supplying multiple requests or say duplicate request in requestbody.*

Here is an example:

**Request:**

```
{
  "Business": {
    "name": "ABC"
  }
}
{
  "Business": {
    "name": "XYZ"
  }
}
```

**Controller's method:**

```
Report getData(@RequestBody final Info info){ 
//Some code here... 
}
```

Here *Info* is model class which further have *Business* class with getter and setter methods

When I POST above request at the time of deserialization first block converted into java object but second one gets simply ignored. I know this is valid json but couldn't understand why 2nd block gets ignored at the time of deserialization .

I tried Deserialization and jackson parser properties but couldn't find any readily available solution. I am using jackson library and Spring Boot framework.

**The behaviour which I am expecting is that it should throw Bad Request instead of treating it as valid json request.**

Suggest an approach to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show your controller method's signature with the used `@RequestBody`

Comment: this looks like an list of same objects. Are you receiving it in a list ??

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Report getData(@RequestBody final Info info){
//Some code here...
}
Here Info is model class which further have Business class with getter and setter methods

Comment: @ygbgames No this isn't list. This is mutiple or duplicate request supplied in POST request. Which I want to validate and throw Bad Request. Ultimately, I want to notify consumer that he is passing unacceptable json request.

Comment: Oh then in springboot you can implement interceptor and validate if it is parsable json as per your pojo or not and action as per that.

Answer (score 0):

You are sendind a `list` so it's better to be in below format:

```
{
"Businesses" : [
       {"name": "ABC"},
       {"name": "ABC"}
       ]
}
```

And in case of recieving a `list`, your method in controller should accept a list:

```
@POST
@Path("/somePath")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
your_method(ArrayList<Business> businesses){
     //...your code
}
```

Comment: I really don't want to send a list in request. In actual request should contain only single request not the list, but I can't control end-users or consumer they might send request like I mentioned in problem, In such case I would need to validate it and should say Bad Request. Hope you understood what I mean to say?

Answer (score 0):

So your `@RequestBody` annotation should use a `List<Info>` instead of `Info` and you should also use a json list when sending your data `[{"name": "ABC"},{"name": "XYZ"}]`

Comment: I really don't want to send a list in request. In actual request should contain only single request not the list, but I can't control end-users or consumer they might send multiple request in body like I mentioned in problem, In such case I would need to validate it and should say **Bad Request**. Hope you understood what I mean to say?

Comment: So then it looks like you have a multipart requestbody. You can quick search it in the web and see if it's what you're looking for

Comment: Well.. I am not sure. As per my knowledge multipart usually associated with files which is not in my case. Can you pls share some links which can help me with respect to problem statement which I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can POST a JsonArray like that:

```
[
    {
      "Business": {
        "name": "ABC"
      }
    }
    {
      "Business": {
        "name": "XYZ"
      }
    }
]
```

than just loop over the JsonObjects. 
You can use Google's GSON or what i personally like to use, the MinimalJson (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.eclipsesource.minimal-json/minimal-json) dependency to parse objects and determine if they comply the standard.

Comment: I understand I can send as same but what in case it is supplied like I mentioned in problem. I would like to validate that case.